# Distinguist different paypal donate buttons

Tags: paypal

I have a client that needs to know details about where a donation is coming from when received into her PayPal site. She runs different events that have donations but needs to keep track of which event the donation is coming from. They are going to the same organization.

Example

Gala event - donation button

website donation - donation button

Charity event - donation button

How would I set this up so that the client knows which event the donation is coming from or if it is coming from the website donation area? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to include the CUSTOM parameter in your donation button and give it a value that uniquely identifies each event.  This could be an event ID or some sort of text value, whatever works for you.

That value would then be available when working with [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/), looking at transaction history in PayPal, or downloading transaction spreadsheets, etc.

Comment: Thank you. What I did was add a donation ID so that my client can tell what the donation is for. I believe this will be workable for now. I am not sure what you meant by CUSTOM parameters. I hope that is what you meant. If not, please explain further so that I understand in the future how to do this properly. Thanks.

Comment: The parameter name is actually called custom.  You can put anything you want in that parameter up to 256 characters.